# Image slide show and IF condition

Tags: if-statement, slideshow

This is the HTML code of my slide show

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" id="image" style="width:230px; border-bottom:2px solid #000">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Start Slide Show" onClick="startSlideShow()">
<input type="button" value="Stop Slide Show" onClick="stopSlideShow()">
```

And this is the code of my Javascript, but the if condition is not working here. Can you please solve this problem?

```
  <script>
    var intervalID;

    function startSlideShow(){
        intervalID = setInterval(changeImage, 800); 
    }

    function stopSlideShow(){
        clearInterval(intervalID);  
    }

    function changeImage(){
        var imageSrc = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src");
        var currentImageNumber = imageSrc.substring(imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 2);
        if(currentImageNumber == 7){
            currentImageNumber == 0;
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = currentImageNumber;
        document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src",  "images/" + (Number(currentImageNumber)+1) + ".jpg");     

    }
    changeImage();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the part of the code that says

```
currentImageNumber == 0
```

should be

```
currentImageNumber = 0
```

in order to cycle through the images